# How to make a program to list all possible three digit addition solutions to a user inputted number. (can not use zero)

Tags: c, for-loop, recursion

I want to make a C program to that will give me all the possible ways to add three numbers(without using zero) to equal whatever the user entered. For example, if the user entered 4, the solutions would be 1+1+2. If the user entered 3, the only solution would be 1+1+1. From what I noticed, after 4, there is always another solution. So, if 5 was entered there would be 2 solutions..1+1+3,2+2+1...and if 6 was entered, there would be three solutions and the solution number would always increase by 1. The thing I can't figure out is the logic on how to get all the answers everytime. My current code is kind of brute force and just gives me the 1+1+(whatever number is left) solution and the other part only works for one solution and only if it is odd. My current code is as follows:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int num;
   printf("Enter a number: ");
   scanf("%d",&num);
   if(num < 3)
     printf("No solution.\n");

   int p = num/2;
   int q = num%2;
   int v = num - (p+q);

   printf("%d+%d+%d\n",p,q,v);//prints a single solution but only works        for odd numbers

   int k = num - 2;
   printf("1+1+%d\n",k);
   //prints a single solution but only 1+1+whatever is left
   return 0;
}
```

Any advice or different way to approach this would be very helpful. I was told I could do 3 nested for loops but I was looking for a different approach.

Comment: Hint: Solve the adding just two numbers case first, spot the pattern, then move on to the adding three numbers case.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses 3 nested `for` loops, (although I see that something else would be preferred). There is at least one other way:

- Using recursion
- There might be another one: solving the problem mathematically (and this would be the most elegant)

It is still brute force, but doesn't try some combinations that we know for sure that won't yield a (good) result.
Since the numbers order is not important meaning that for example:

***6*** =

- ***1* + *2* + *3***
- ***1* + *3* + *2***
- ***2* + *1* + *3***
- ***2* + *3* + *1***
- ***3* + *1* + *2***
- ***3* + *2* + *1***

all *6* permutations of *(1, 2, 3)* constitute a **single** solution, only one variant of the 3 numbers permutations matters. 
That we can use it in our advantage: we chose the 3 number sequence where *No1* <= *No2* <= *No3* (*No1* + *No2* + *No3* = **N** (entered by the user)).
That translates in lesser operations to compute: instead for each of the 3 indexes (`i`, `j`, `k`) which correspond to (*No1*, *No2*, *No3*) to swipe across the whole ***[1 .. n]*** interval:

1. The outer index (`i`) only iterates *[1 .. n / **3**]* (it makes no point to go higher since the other 2 numbers are greater or equal to it, and if it did the sum would be greater than *n*). This alone reduces the number of operations to one third
2. The mid index (`j`) only iterates *[i .. n / **2**]* (it doesn't go below the previous one since `i` <= `j`, and makes no sense to go higher than ***n / 2*** since the other number will be greater or equal to it, and again the sum would be greater than *n*)
3. The inner index (`k`) only iterates *[j .. n - 2]* (it's obvious why).

**Notes**:

- It might be possible (actually, I'm pretty sure) that the operations can be reduced even more
- The last 3 variables declared (having the bogus names) are for speeding things up: they are calculated once, at the beginning (although I might be reinventing the wheel here since I'm pretty sure that the compiler is optimizing these kind of situations). 
  But, regardless of the optimizations, the algorithm is still ***O(n ** 3)*** which is highly inefficient. I feel that I'm missing something obvious, but I can't put my finger on it
- I checked (not very thoroughly though), and it doesn't seem to skip solutions

*code.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void generate(int n) {
    int i, j, k, count = 0, n_div_3 = n / 3, n_div_2 = n / 2, n_minus_1 = n - 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= n_div_3; i++)
        for (j = i; j <= n_div_2; j++)
            for (k = j; k < n_minus_1; k++)
                if (i + j + k == n) {
                    printf("Solution %d: %d %d %d\n", count++, i, j, k);
                    break;
                }
    printf("\n%d solutions\n", count);
}

int main () {
    int num;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    generate(num);
    return 0;
}
```